# Cannot get data from tkinter Entry()

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to allow the user to input five values, click a button to finalize those values, then write those values to a file. Code:

```
def mb_add_gui(self):

    self.optionsLabel.grid_forget()



    global a,b,c,d,e


    a = StringVar()
    b = StringVar()
    c = StringVar()
    d = StringVar()
    e = StringVar()


    add_gui_entry_brand = Entry(self.startLabel, textvariable=a).grid(row=0, column=1)
    add_gui_entry_model = Entry(self.startLabel, textvariable=b).grid(row=1, column=1)
    add_gui_entry_serial = Entry(self.startLabel, textvariable=c).grid(row=2,column=1)
    add_gui_entry_work = Entry(self.startLabel, textvariable=d).grid(row=3, column=1)
    add_gui_entry_ram = Entry(self.startLabel,textvariable=e).grid(row=4, column=1)
    add_gui_entry_brand_text = Label(self.startLabel, text="Brand:").grid(row=0, column=0)
    add_gui_entry_model_text = Label(self.startLabel, text="Model:").grid(row=1, column=0)
    add_gui_entry_serial_text = Label(self.startLabel, text="Serial Number:").grid(row=2, column=0)
    add_gui_entry_work_text = Label(self.startLabel, text="Is it working?:").grid(row=3, column=0)
    add_gui_entry_ram_text = Label(self.startLabel, text="RAM Type:").grid(row=4, column=0)

    def final_data():
        global data
        data = [a.get(), b.get(),c.get(),d.get(),e.get()]
        return data

    finalize = Button(self.startLabel, text="Add!", command=final_data).grid(row=5, columnspan=2)
```

'''Allows the addition of a motherboard'''

```
def mb_add():


    with open("motherboards.txt", "a") as file:


        file.write("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}".format(data[0].upper(), data[1].upper(), data[2].upper(), data[3].upper(), data[4].upper()))
        file.write("\n")
        print("Motherboard added!")
        file.flush()
        file.close()
    return
```

"""however, when i run this, i get an error saying that the global data variable is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you have created a global variable, but need to define it as global in all the functions you want to use it in (so python knows you wish to use that global variable, and not another same named local variable which it incidentally can't find). Also you are creating your variables e.g. `finalize` and then positioning them on the same line, so they will return `Nonetype`, you have to position them on the next line e.g.

```
finalize = Button(self.startLabel, text="Add!", command=final_data)
finalize.grid()
```

to solve your problem you must add this line to your `mb_add` function:

```
global data
```

hope that helps!